# How to have one enum with an optional case for tableview section

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have 3 sections to show if an optional variable is not nil and only 2 if it is. 
What i want is to have all this in an enum(or struct if that is not possible).

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let currentTraining = self.currentTraining {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: currentTraining)
        case 1:
            return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case 2:
            return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
        default:
            fatalError("No more sections allowed")
        }
    } else {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case 1:
            return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
        default:
            fatalError("No more sections allowed")
        }
    }
}
```

I had something in mind to wrap all this in enums(or structs if that makes more sense) and just switch the cases and shorten my code in `cellForRow`

```
enum TrainingSection {
    case qrCode
    case trainingMethod
    // if its nil to make nothing if yes do call the method
    case currentTraining(FTCurrentTraining)
}
```

Comment: So the goal is to shorten the code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your intention is to hide a section in some cases. The typical way to do that is to set the row height to zero. You're correct that you should generally use an enum for the section IDs. For example, you could do something like this:

```
enum TrainingSection: Int {
    case currentTraining
    case qrCode
    case trainingMethod
}

var currentTraining: FTCurrentTraining?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch TrainingSection(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
    case .currentTraining:
        if let currentTraining = currentTraining {
            return currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: currentTraining)
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()    // Just return an empty cell
        }
    case .qrCode:
        return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
    case .trainingMethod:
        return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch TrainingSection(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
    case .currentTraining where currentTraining == nil:
        return 0
    default:
        return tableView.rowHeight
    }
}
```

An enum with associated data is the wrong tool here. Conceptually there are section identifiers, and completely separately there is a piece of state (`currentTraining`). Merging those doesn't make sense in this context. That said, you can go a completely different way and rebuild your sections depending on your state. This is very useful in some contexts, but here I think it's over-complicated. Even so, for completeness:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    enum TrainingSection {
        case currentTraining(FTCurrentTraining)
        case qrCode
        case trainingMethod
    }

    var sections: [TrainingSection] = [.qrCode, .trainingMethod]

    func updateSections() {
        // When some kind of state changes, rebuild `sections` to include the relevant sections
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { sections.count }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch sections[indexPath.section] {
        case .currentTraining(let training):
            return currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: currentTraining)
        case .qrCode:
            return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case .trainingMethod:
            return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
        default:
            fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thnx for your answer and time - but playing with heights in a tableview is not the correct solution i think.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of how to shorten your code with enums or structs, but here's how I would shorten it - with an array of closures.

```
var sectionClosures = [
    { qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath) }
    { trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath) }
]
if let currentTraining = self.currentTraining {
    sectionClosures.insert(
        { currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: currentTraining) }, 
        at: 0)
}
if (0..<sectionClosures.count).contains(indexPath.section) {
    return sectionClosures[indexPath.section]()
} else {
    fatalError("No more sections allowed")
}
```

Based on your edit, I think you can probably add a method that converts one of your enum values to a table view cell. Instead of an array of closures, you'll be using an array of your enums to represent the sections.

First, you also need to add the `tableView` and `indexPath` associated values to your enum cases:

```
enum TrainingSection {
    case qrCode(UITableView, IndexPath)
    case trainingMethod(UITableView, IndexPath)
    case currentTraining(UITableView, IndexPath, FTCurrentTraining)
}
```

And then do the same as the first code snippet, except with this enum:

```
var sections = [
    TrainingSection.qrCode(tableView, indexPath)
    .trainingMethod(tableView, indexPath)
]
if let currentTraining = self.currentTraining {
    // here, you can reassign the whole sections array if you find it clearer that way
    sections.insert(
        .currentTraining(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining), 
        at: 0)
}
if (0..<sections.count).contains(indexPath.section) {
    return tableViewCell(for: sections[indexPath.section])
} else {
    fatalError("No more sections allowed")
}
```

`tableViewCell(for:)` is simply something like this:

```
func tableViewCell(for trainingSection: TrainingSection) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch trainingSection {
    case .qrCode(let tv, let ip): return qrCodeCell(tv, ip)
    case .trainingMethod(let tv, let ip): return trainingMethodCell(tv, ip)
    case .currentTraining(let tv, let ip, let ct): return currentTrainingCell(tv, ip, currentTraining: ct)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a solution to shorten my code but not clear and good - this has so many downsides like scaling for other purposes e.g. when i want to add logic in the `indexPath.section = 1` or others

Comment: Whether it is clear is subjective, but I do agree my solution is not scalable. But if you want to add more logic in the `indexPath.section == 1` case, you can just add more to the closures. I think it would be useful to edit your question to show what kind of code you had in mind (I have interpreted your question to be "least repetition" as your original code has a lot of it), otherwise it would just involve a _lot_ of me guessing  around. @Muli

Comment: I have added something, but it is hard for me what to suggest as i want only to shorten it up and scalable :/. Thnx a lot for your help btw.

Comment: @Muli Your enum reminds me of [`RxDataSources`](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources), which runs on RxSwift and RxCocoa. That is a really good way of declaratively create table views. Maybe you should look into that while I think of another solution.

Comment: @Muli See the edit. If you want a solution "smarter" than that, you'd probably end up with something very similar to RxDataSources.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, but that closures snippet i still have to implement inside my tableview delegate method and i think this is still to much code :/

Cool solution though, I haven't thought about closures.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to make cleaner code.

You can do it as follow:

```swift
enum TrainingSection {
    case qrCode
    case trainingMethod
    case currentTraining(FTCurrentTraining)

   static func getSections(for element: FTCurrentTraining?) -> [TrainingSection] {
       if let element: FTCurrentTraining = element {
           return [
               .currentTraining(element),
               .qrCode,
               .trainingMethod,
           ]
       } else { 
           return [
               .qrCode,
               .trainingMethod,
           ]
       }
   }
}

class X: UITableViewDataSource {
    var element: FTCurrentTraining? {
        didSet {
            sections = TrainingSection.getSections(for: element)
        }
    }

    private var sections: [TrainingSection] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: TableViewDelegate
    func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView, 
        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard indexPath.section < sections.count else {
            // it's a bit paranoid assert fell free to remove it
            fatalError("No more sections allowed")
        }
        switch sections[indexPath.section] {
        case .qrCode:
            return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case .trainingMethod:
            return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case .currentTraining(let currentTraining):
            return currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: currentTraining)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a handy computed (or stored) array for sections:

```
private var sections: [TrainingSection] {
    let regularSections: [TrainingSection] = [.qrCode, .trainingMethod]
    if let currentTraining = self.currentTraining {
        return [.currentTraining(currentTraining)] + regularSections
    } else {
        return regularSections
    }
}
```

Then you can implement an extension on your `enum`:

```
fileprivate extension TrainingSection { // Since it is extremely coupled with the `TableView`, It should be filePrivate

    func cell(in tableView: UITableView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch self {
        case .qrCode: return qrCodeCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case .trainingMethod: return trainingMethodCell(tableView, indexPath)
        case .currentTraining(let current): currentTrainingCell(tableView, indexPath, currentTraining: current)
        }
    }
}
```

Then `cellForRow...` function will be a single line of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    sections[indexPath.section].cell(in: tableView, for: indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TrainingSection {
    enum cell {
        case qrCode
        case trainingMethod
        case currentTraining(FTCurrentTraining)
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellTypes: [TrainingSection.cell] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.generateData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellType = cellTypes[indexPath.row]
        switch cellType {
        case .currentTraining(let currentTraining):
            print("Current Training cell \(currentTraining)")
        case .trainingMethod:
            print("training cell")
        case .qrCode:
            print("qr code cell")
        }
        return UITableViewCell.init()
    }
    func generateData() {
        cellTypes.removeAll()
        if self.currentTraining != nil {
            cellTypes.append(.currentTraining(currentTraining))
        }
        cellTypes.append(.qrCode)
        cellTypes.append(.trainingMethod)
    }

}
```